# L'agent de la proposition infinitive objet direct

Tags: syntaxe

Bonjour,

Je voudrais savoir si dans les trois phrases suivantes l’agent de l’infinitif peut aussi prendre l’accusatif au lieu du datif :

1) Laissons faire **aux poètes**.
2) Cela, peu à peu, **lui** laissait espérer dans la clémence du sort.
3) Elle fléchissait le cou comme on **leur** voit faire à toutes.

Donc, pourrait-on formuler ces phrases de la façon suivante ?

1) Laissons faire **les** poètes.
2) Cela, peu à peu, **le** laissait espérer dans la clémence du sort.
3) Elle fléchissait le cou comme on **les** voit faire toutes.

Answer (score 1):

A1/ « laisser qqn faire qqc » et « laisser faire qqc à qqn » sont des formes utilisables mais pas "laisser faire à qqn »; donc la première phrase n'est pas correcte.

- Laissez faire le travail aux spécialistes.
- Laissez faire la poésie aux poètes.

« laisser faire qqn » est une forme utilisable et on peut donc dire (ou écrire, évidemment) « Laissez faire les poètes.».

A2/ La forme serait « laisser  à qqn espérer prep qqc »; cette forme existe peut être et la phrase serait acceptable mais il est plus sûr d'utiliser la seconde version qui, elle, est correcte : « Cela, peu à peu le laissait espérer dans la clémence du sort. »

En rapport avec ce cas il faut considérer que des phrases de ce type, légèrement modifiées, peuvent être tout à fait correctes et même ne pas avoir de construction alternative ; par exemple,

« Cela, peu à peu, lui laissait dans l'esprit une impression de désarroi. »,

où la construction est « laisser qqc à qqn » ne peut être construite qu'avec « lui » en raison de la prep « à »; cela peut cependant paraitre évident.

A3/ Selon cette phrase la construction serait « voir faire à qqn »; comme « laisser faire à qqn » elle n'existe pas et seulement la seconde phrase est correcte: « Elle fléchissait le cou comme on les voit faire toutes. »

**Remarque**  Si on voulait être plus spécifique on pourrait dire :

« Elle fléchissait le cou comme on les voit toutes faire cela. » ou

« Elle fléchissait le cou comme on les voit toutes le faire. »

Cela montre que l'impression que l'on peut avoir que « lui » et « leur » serait des "rappels" de l'objet sont des impressions fausses.

Comment: @Toto Je viens de vérifier votre correction de ma réponse et je crois que votre insistance sur  certaines pratiques en matière de ponctuation est extrême; il n'existe pas dans le français de pratique unique et la mienne est essentiellement celle du TLFi: les points près du texte, les deux-points aussi et même les points-virgule; de plus je tiens au principe traditionnel des phrases qui se terminent par un point ou un point virgule.

Comment: Le dernier commentaire n'est pas tout à fait correct en ce qui concerne « les points près du texte, les deux-points aussi et même les points-virgule » ; cela n'est pas vrai de tous les commentaires qui sont faits dans le TLFi. C'est vrai en ce qui concerne les exemples cependant. Il semble aussi que d'après ce que l'on peut lire dans le Wikipedia un effort d'uniformisation aurait été fait, qui tendrait à imposer les principes que vous utilisez : ponctuation basse près du mot, ponctuation haute après un espace .

Comment: Désolé si j'ai choqué. J'essaie d'appliquer, autant que faire se peut les règles de la « bible » en la matière, https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l'Imprimerie_nationale

Comment: @Toto N'en tenez pas compte, je suis un peu perdu avec tous ces systèmes différents: j'écris d'habitude mes textes en Latex, ce qui permet d'écrire la ponctuation haute sans espace (le programme met l'espace) puis il m'arrive de lire de l'anglais, dont la ponctuation est basée sur le principe inverse (ponctuation haute près des mots) et enfin j'ai souvent à vérifier des exemples dans le TLFi où apparemment toute la langue du passé est écrite selon un autre système.

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. À votre avis donc la deuxième variante de toutes les trois phrases est, soit la seule correcte, soit la plus courante. Sachez pourtant que les premières trois (avec le datif) ont été conçues par des cerveaux français, 1) Gide, 2) Carco 3) Proust, respectivement, pendant que les deuxièmes trois par le mien. Votre opinion m’est utile tout de même, parce qu’elle m’aide à choisir entre deux variantes la plus courante, notamment celle avec l’accusatif.

Comment: @saquiwej Il est certain qu'il faille se baser sur la production des maitres du langage; cependant l'esprit innovateur d'une sommité littéraire n'est pas une garantie d'une véritable appartenance au langage; nombreux sont les cas de création dont l'usage n'a jamais dépassé les limites de l'ouvrage desquels il sont issus; pour prendre un cas concret, en espérant que vous ayez un peu de familiarité avec Antoine de Saint Éxupéry et son ouvrage inachevé, *La Citadelle*, croyez vous que ses constructions telles que « J'étais seigneur barbare… » et « Je vous demande de devenir. » (continué)

Comment: @saquiwej  aient quelque chose de naturel? Croyez-vous qu'elles constitueraient un apport au langage? Donc, malgré que les premières phrases se trouvent dans les œuvres des personnages cités je ne leur  confère pas un degré de légitimité plus grand; je n'irais pas jusqu'à les juger incorrect, mais je donne ma préférence au autres en tant que formes qui m'apparaissent plus saines. Il me semble par exemple que l'on puisse entendre la seconde phrase du premier groupe assez souvent, mais je lui préfère de beaucoup la seconde du second groupe.